# Mount partition as read-only until reboot

Tags: linux, mount, boot, read-only

Is it possible on Linux to mount a partition as read-only at boot time and make sure it cannot be re-mounted as read-write until next boot / power off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and No.

*Yes*: it is possible to specify the mount as `ro` for almost any FS in the fstab. Naturally, this will take effect at every boot, so if you want to mount the partition R/W next boot, you'll need to modify the fstab before shutting down.

*No*: root is able to remount the partition as R/W at any point in time.

Comment: Sure, mounting read-only is easy. The question was more if it's possible to lock it that way...
Thank you for the confirmation that it's not.